# How to interrupt device audio to play a sound and then let the device audio continue on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I have an app where the user can play voice messages received from other users. Playing the voice messages should interrupt device audio (music, podcast, etc playing from other apps), play the voice messages and then let the device audio continue.

Here is a use specific use case I am trying to achieve

- the user starts playing music on the device via Apple Music
- the user opens the app and taps a voice message
- the Apple Music stops
- voice message in the app plays
- Apple Music continues playing

With setting `AVAudioSession`s category to `.ambient` I can play the voice message "over" the playing Apple Music, but that is not what I need exactly.

If I use the `.playback` category that makes the Apple Music stop, plays the voice message in the app but Apple Music does not continue playing afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, Apple has provided a "protocol" for interrupting and resuming background audio, and in a downloadable example, I show you what it is and prove that it works:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch14p653backgroundPlayerAndInterrupter

In that example, there are *two* projects, representing two different apps. You run *both* of them simultaneously. BackgroundPlayer plays sound in the background; Interrupter interrupts it, pausing it, and when it is finished interrupting, BackgroundPlayer resumes.

This, as you will see, is done by having Interrupter *change its audio session category* from ambient to playback while interrupting, and *changing it back* when finished, along with first deactivating itself entirely while sending the `.notifyOthersOnDeactivation` signal:

```
func playFile(atPath path:String) {
    self.player?.delegate = nil
    self.player?.stop()
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    guard let p = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: fileURL) else {return} // nicer
    self.player = p
    // error-checking omitted
    
    // switch to playback category while playing, interrupt background audio
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode:.default)
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    
    self.player.prepareToPlay()
    self.player.delegate = self
    let ok = self.player.play()
    print("interrupter trying to play \(path): \(ok)")
}

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) { // *
    let sess = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    // this is the key move
    try? sess.setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    // now go back to ambient
    try? sess.setCategory(.ambient, mode:.default)
    try? sess.setActive(true)
    delegate?.soundFinished(self)
}
```

The trouble, however, is that response to `.notifyOthersOnDeactivation` is entirely dependent on the other app being well behaved. My other app, BackgroundPlayer, *is* well behaved. This is what it does:

```
self.observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:
    AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) {
        [weak self] n in
        guard let self = self else { return } // legal in Swift 4.2
        let why = n.userInfo![AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as! UInt
        let type = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType(rawValue: why)!
        switch type {
        case .began:
            print("interruption began:\n\(n.userInfo!)")
        case .ended:
            print("interruption ended:\n\(n.userInfo!)")
            guard let opt = n.userInfo![AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as? UInt else {return}
            let opts = AVAudioSession.InterruptionOptions(rawValue: opt)
            if opts.contains(.shouldResume) {
                print("should resume")
                self.player.prepareToPlay()
                let ok = self.player.play()
                print("bp tried to resume play: did I? \(ok as Any)")
            } else {
                print("not should resume")
            }
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
}
```

As you can see, we register for interruption notifications, and if we *are* interrupted, we look for the `.shouldResume` option — which is the result of the interrupter setting the `notifyOthersOnDeactivation` in the first place.

So far, so good. But there's a snag. Some apps are *not* well behaved in this regard. And the most non-well-behaved is Apple's own Music app! Thus it is actually *impossible* to get the Music app to do what you want it to do. You are better off using *ducking*, where the system just adjusts the relative levels of the two apps for you, allowing the background app (Music) to continue playing but more quietly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped to understand how to use it correctly, however, I followed your example I created 2 projects one for the player and one for the interrupter, I put your code there I see all the logs, the problem is that after the interrupter finish playback I do get this finish event on the main player, but `self.player.prepareToPlay()` and `play()` method itself returns `false`. What am I missing?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Are you claiming that my code, as written in my projects / workspace, doesn't work and playing doesn't resume? Because I assure you it does.

Answer (score 1):

You've already discovered that you can interrupt other audio apps by activating a `.playback` category audio session. When you finish playing your audio and want the interrupted audio to continue, deactivate your audio session and pass the `notifyOthersOnDeactivation` option.

e.g.

```
try! audioSession.setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
```

Comment: But the trouble is that you have no guarantee that the other app will respond to that. Apple's Music app, in particular, does not.

Comment: yeah. maybe ducking is more reliable

Answer (score 0):

I think those apps that should continue like Apple Music, Spotify, Radio apps etc implement the functionality to handle interruptions and when another app's audio is deactivated / wants to hand back responsibility of the audio.

So could you try and see if this works

```
// I play the audio using this AVAudioPlayer
var player: AVAudioPlayer?

// Implement playing a sound
func playSound() {
    
    // Local url for me, but you could configure as you need
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "se_1",
                                    withExtension: "wav")
    else { return }
    
    do {
        // Set the category to playback to interrupt the current audio
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback,
                                                        mode: .default)
        
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        
        // This is to know when the sound has ended
        player?.delegate = self
        
        player?.play()
        
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

extension AVAudioInterruptVC: AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer,
                                     successfully flag: Bool) {
        
        do {
            
            // When the sound has ended, notify other apps
            // You can do this where ever you want, I just show the
            // example of doing it when the audio has ended
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                .setActive(false, options: [.notifyOthersOnDeactivation])
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
}
```